# Using k8s to deploy jenkins and make slave Pods to perform tasks, how to put files or installation packages generated in the pod into jenkins pvc

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I deployed jenkins and used the slave pod to run it. I used the local pv mode of openebs, deployed jenkins and volume on the same node. I used the volume mode to transfer the data generated by the pod. It is shared in the jenkins volume of the host computer. My task is to download the code and add some installation packages to it, but it takes a long time to download the packages. I hope that the slave pod will not be downloaded every time it is deployed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
// groovy公共变量
def PROJECT = "CI-code"
def WORKDIR_PATH = "/opt/status"
def DOWNLOAD_KUBE_DOWNLOAD_URL = "xxx/kube-1.19.0-v2.2.0-amd64.tar.gz"
def PVC_PATH = "/var/openebs/local/pvc-8e8f9830-9bdc-494d-ac45-19310cbda035/cloudybase"

pipeline {
   agent {
   kubernetes {
      yaml """
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: jenkins-slave
  namespace: devops-tools
spec:
  containers:
  - name: jnlp
    image: "xxx/google_containers/jenkins-slave-jdk11-wget:latest"
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    securityContext:
      privileged: true
      runAsUser: 0
    volumeMounts:
      - name: docker-cmd
        mountPath: /usr/bin/docker
      - name: docker-sock
        mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
      - name: code
        mountPath: /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/${PROJECT}
  volumes:
    - name: docker-cmd
      hostPath:
        path: /usr/bin/docker
    - name: docker-sock
      hostPath:
        path: /var/run/docker.sock
    - name: code
      hostPath:
        path: ${PVC_PATH}
"""
    }
  }

   stages {
      stage('拉取代码') {
         steps {
            git branch: 'release-2.2.0', credentialsId: 'e17ba069-aa8b-4bfd-9c9e-3f3956914f09', url: 'xxx/deployworker.git'
         }
      }

   stage('下载依赖包到组件包对应目录') {
      steps {
            sh """
               logging() {
                 echo -e "\033[32m $(/bin/date)\033[0m" - $@
                }
             
               main () {
                 logging Check ${DOWNLOAD_KUBE_DOWNLOAD_URL} installation package if download ...
                    if [ ! -f "${PVC_PATH}/kube_status_code" ];then
                     download_kube
                    fi
                }

                download_kube () {
                DOWNLOAD_KUBE_NAME=$(echo ${DOWNLOAD_KUBE_DOWNLOAD_URL} | /bin/sed 's|.*/||')
                
                cd / && { /bin/curl -O ${DOWNLOAD_KUBE_DOWNLOAD_URL} ; cd -; }
                if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
                  echo "Failed"
                  exit 1
                fi
 
                echo 'true' > ${W_PATH}/kube_status_code
                mkdir -p /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/deploywork/Middleware-choreography/kubeQ/kubeQ/
                tar xf /\${DOWNLOAD_KUBE_NAME} -C /home/jenkins/agent/workspace/deploywork/Middleware-choreography/kubeQ/kubeQ/

                if [ "$?" -ne "0" ]; then
                  echo "Failed"
                  exit 1
                fi
                }
            """
         }
      }
```

Comment: I wrote some shells to judge whether it has been downloaded. I think I should judge it in the container, but every time the container is new, so I have to re-download the package every time. This installation package is relatively large

Answer (score 0):

Hi `zccharts` from the above explanation I can get that you are trying to create your container from scratch every time and it is consuming time. This can be solved by creating your base container image with all the packages installed and you can use it in your pipeline for deploying your application.

Comment: Currently, I mount locally through the volume, and then make a judgment, so each time the pipeline executes, I can reduce each download time depending on whether or not the installation package is downloaded

Comment: When you say make a mirror package, is it dynamic production? The package downloaded each time is not fixed, and maybe a new package is needed for the next construction. What is the process like?

Comment: @zccharts Initially when you said a large package I took the same set of packages into consideration and gave the answer. So if the packages are dynamic you can try to have a mirror repository where you have your packages using which you can make your deployments and your repo server will be in sync with primary repo server. This will be helpful to reduce delays in your deployments. This might increase the burden on your costing.